# Is there an alternative approach to using Union for this scenario in SQL?

Tags: sql, union

I have a table A that has data like the following

```
Index Chapter1 Chapter2 .... Chapter20
1     CHE      MTH           NULL
2     ML       NULL          BIO
3     NULL     DB            HIST
```

I want to build a view on top of the table which should give me result like the following

```
Index Chapter 
1     CHECh1
1     MTHCh2
..
2     MLCh1
..
2     BIOCh2 
3     DBCh2
...and so on
```

I could build a view which gives me the correct result by using UNION operation.

```
SELECT Index, CASE WHEN Chapter1 IS NOT NULL THEN Chapter1||'Ch1' END
from A
union
SELECT Index, CASE WHEN Chapter2 IS NOT NULL THEN Chapter2||'Ch2' END
from A
...
..
SELECT Index, CASE WHEN Chapter2 IS NOT NULL THEN Chapter20||'Ch20' END
from A
```

Is there any other optimized approach of doing this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @ShwetaPri, what database are you using? Postgres, MySQL?

Comment: Sorry about that. I am using SAP HANA database.

Answer (score 0):

Various forms of SQL support lateral joins.  One syntax looks like:

```
select t.index, v.chapter || 'Ch' || v.n
from t cross join lateral
     (values (chapter1, 1), (chapter2, 2), . . . ) v(chapter, n)
where chapter is not null;
```

Do not despair, though, if your database does not.  You can do something similar with a `cross join`:

```
select id,  chapter || 'Ch' || n
from (select t.id,
             (case when n = 1 then chapter1
                   when n = 2 then chapter2
                   . . .
                   when n = 20 then chapter20
              end) as chapter, v.n
      from t cross join
           (values (1), (2), (3), . . . ) v(n)  -- or the equivalent for your database to get a table with 20 numbers
     ) tc
where chapter is not null;
```

Both of these approaches only scan the table once, which should be a performance improvement.  If the "table" is really a complicated query, this can be a big improvement.

Comment: Looks promising.I will try the above mentioned approach.